# InsertMany throw E11000 duplicate key error but insert successfully

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose to insert bulk data to database.
The `insertMany` throw E11000 duplicate key error although the data is saved succeed in database.

Here is my codes:

```
  var data = [
      {_id: '598d7ae7c3148a6d853866e8'}, 
      {_id: '598d7afdc3148a6d853866f4'}
    ]
Movies.insertMany(data, function(error, docs) {});
```

This happen infrequently.

Appreciated any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

MongoDB doesn't support transactions.

Because your operation is ordered (the default), MongoDB starts inserting documents until either all documents have been written, or it hits an error (for instance, when one of the `_id`'s already exists in the database), at which point MongoDB will stop inserting the rest of the documents.

So if you try to insert 10 documents, and after 5 documents an error occurs, the first 5 documents will get inserted, but the rest won't. This is documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#insert-several-document-specifying-an-id-field).

That same document also suggests how to deal with this: disable ordering, because *"With `ordered` [set] to `false`, the insert operation would continue with any remaining documents."*

```
Movies.insertMany(data, { ordered : false }, function(error, docs) { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read about this before create question here. But in my case there is no duplicated key (_id) which can cause the error E11000. My target collection is totally new.

Comment: I had figured out the problem. It's a bug of Studio 3T. I drop the collection, but after refresh, it's back.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to add this here for anyone who comes across this issue. I had the same exact issue and the reason I was getting this duplicate key error was because my old mongoose model used to enforce a UNIQUE constraint on one of my keys AND when I removed these unique constraints from my mongoose Model, I forgot to completely remove ALL existing indexes from the database. When I ran: `db.mycollection.getIndexes()`, I found that the old unique indexes were STILL in my database EVEN after removing all documents from each collection.

To get rid of these indexes I ran: `db.mycollection.dropIndexes()` in the shell.

Another tip I have for you: If you have a database seeding script that clears your collections & inserts fresh data (e.g for your test suite), I recommend you drop all indexes for each collection AFTER clearing your database. You can drop indexes for your models in mongoose like so: `myMongooseModel.collection.dropIndexes()`

Answer (score 1):

I had figured out the problem. It's a bug of Studio 3T. I drop all collections then import new collections then refresh collections tree. Some dropped collections are back.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a function to find and update, and iterate the array data

set upset and new with true

```
  _storeLive(data) {
    shemaLive.findOneAndUpdate({
      _id: data._id
    }, data, {
      upsert: true,
      new: true
    }, (err, event) => {
      if (err) {} else {}
    });
  }


customArray.forEach(obj => _storeLive(obj));
```